# How to set a Tableview cell alpha value

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`. And i have 4 cell in that Tableview.

My Tableview alpha value is 0.8.

But my requirement is i want to first 3 cell will be alpha value 0.8 and 4th cell will be 1.0 alpha value.

So how can i set these alpha value according to cell?

Please help me. I am facing this prob from last 2 days.

This is my code:

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
      NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",@"Cell",indexPath.row];
      if (indexPath.row == 0)
      {
         cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil)
         {
             cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
             cell.alpha = 0.8;
         }
      }
      else if (indexPath.row == 1)
      {
            cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
               cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
               cell.alpha = 0.8;
            }
      }
      else if(indexPath.row == 2)
      {
              cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
              if (cell == nil)
              {
                 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                 cell.alpha = 0.8;
              }
       }
       else if (indexPath.row == 3)
       {
              cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
               if (cell == nil)
              {
                   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
                   cell.alpha = 1.0;
              }
       }
        return cell;
     }
```

Comment: Even if your code is not very kind, it should work. So what is the problem?

Comment: If the only difference between the cells is the alpha, I recommend you reuse one cell, and just set the alpha value depending on index path. Also, I'm not sure I get what the problem is. Is the alpha difference not showing? What's the cell's and tableView's background color?

Comment: cell & tableView background color is clear color

Comment: Clear color is transparent means alpha is 0 already. there will be no effect of setting alpha with clear color

Comment: according to above my code what should be table alpha value? now its 1.0.

Comment: your code is having problem.If your issue still not resolved get back.@ Nayak

Comment: No, still now i am struggling. Can u help me?

Comment: sure, I will upadate your code

Answer (score 1):

I hope this single line of code solve your issue

```
cell.contentView.alpha = 0.8
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the cell background color with an alpha value?

`cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.8];`

Answer (score 0):

clearColor's grayscale and alpha = 0, so no matter what alpha you set, it won`t work, you have to have an actual colour so alpha to have visible efects

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
        NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell"];

        cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  UIView *lView_ = [[UIView alloc] init];
     lView_ = [[UIView alloc] init];
        lView_.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:0.6];
        cell.backgroundView = lView_;

        }


   UIView *backview = (UIView *)cell.backgroundView;

        if (indexPath.row == 3)
        {

       backview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:1];

        }
        else
        {
             backview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:0.2];
        }
        return cell;
    }
```

Use the above and check wheather it is working or not.I hope this reolve your issue.

Comment: but what should be tableview alpha value?

Comment: Clear table view background color. And it is better to send the mockup screen of what you need

Comment: same thing u r doing whatever i did. What is the diffrence between these 2 coding?

Comment: no man. Same issue. I can't see any diff between 2 code. I am writting in every condition u r writting on above of validation. what is the diff?

Comment: you are using cell identifier different for each cell.And identifier is used for reusing the cell. Once send the screen shot of what ui you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62098/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-ramesh-muthe).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the cell in this delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.alpha = indexPath.row < 3 ? 0.8 : 1.0;
}
```